# Flexible div blocks

Tags: css, html

I need a three column block such that, if more content in the center (middle column) - side blocks increased.

Now i have this http://s2.ipicture.ru/uploads/20110714/NQ6ZNRsB.png

HTML:

```
<div id="spoiler">
  <div class="left">1</div>
  <div class="middle">
    2<br />
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br />
    hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh<br />
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br />
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br />
  </div>
  <div class="right">3</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
            #spoiler {
            width:500px;
        }
        .left, .middle, .right {
            background:#ffdac0;
            height: auto !important;
            height: 100%; /* for IE6 */
        }
        .left {
            float:left;
            width:100px;
        }
        .middle {
            float:left;
            width:300px;
        }
        .right {
            float:right;
            width:100px;
        }
```

Help please!

Comment: Any way to elaborate a little more? Maybe photoshop a little image of the result that you want?

Comment: can you please explain further what you want to achieve..?

Comment: You want the three columns use all available width and the sides to shrink when the middle column gets wider?

Comment: Ok. I want that all blocks have similar height (auto). Like this http://s1.ipicture.ru/uploads/20110714/qXTGN8Rj.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only changed the css.

http://jsfiddle.net/QvfwN/

```
    #spoiler {
    width:500px;
        background:#ffdac0;
        float: left;
}
.left {
    float:left;
    width:100px;
}
.middle {
    float:left;
    width:300px;
}
.right {
    float:right;
    width:100px;
}
```

Comment: @Vladimir: See also the comments to [ADWs answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6689856/flexible-div-blocks/6690359#6690359) as they are relevant to this answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the background colour from .left, .middle, .right and put it on the #spoiler along with either a float left or have some clearing at the bottom:

```
    #spoiler {
        width:500px;
        background:#ffdac0;
        float: left;
    }
    .left, .middle, .right {
        height: auto !important;
        height: 100%; /* for IE6 */
    }
    .left {
        float:left;
        width:100px;
    }
    .middle {
        float:left;
        width:300px;
    }
    .right {
        float:right;
        width:100px;
    }
```

This will produce the image you're looking for.

Comment: No need for the `height: auto !important; height: 100%;` will work in ie6+ fine without them.

Comment: Actually, `overflow: auto` would be better than floating the wrapper.

Comment: @You In what way? @Vladimir those height values are useless FYI.

Comment: @Lollero: You may not always *want* to float the wrapper, as floating the wrapper has side-effects. Setting `overflow: auto` doesn't affect positioning of the wrapper, while floating it does.

Comment: @You I see no scenario where floating a box like this will have any toubles.

Comment: @Lollero: Such a case could easily be constructed. The point is, floating the element *may* be unacceptable, while setting `overflow: auto` will *always* be acceptable.

Comment: @You I see only one way that could go wrong with floats but it more or less happens with overflow: auto as well.. just not as badly.

Comment: @You Would you mind giving me example where float fails as i really dont see that happening, but i'd like to know.

Comment: @Lollero: Not "fails", but is inappropriate; note the two `div` elements in [this JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/urdh/gjLpM/), and how the second one is, well, a float, when that may not be what you want.

Comment: @You Youre right. Well as long as it needs to be centered dynamically this set-up poses a problem with `float: left`, though it can be overcome by extra `outer-div` but indeed `Overflow: auto;` serves better for that purpose. +1

Answer (score -1):

Simply use a table with 3 TD. This way it will always expand. Divs are not meant to work with eachother like that since they are block elements.

I think it can be done, but the simpler solution is the use of a good ol fashion table :)

Comment: **No.** Tables are *not* for layout.